# Leibniz integral rule - any connection to the Lebesgue dominated convergence theorem?

Tags: real-analysis

If a scalar-valued function f(x,y,z) were smooth and decreases rapidly to zero at infinity (so it is bounded), we're able to differentiate under the integral sign - applying the Leibniz integral rule multiple times.

Is there any connection to the Lebesgue dominated convergence theorem, even though my integrand is not a sequence of functions, but rather just a single function of x,y,z?

Thanks,